# pubspec.yaml Conflicting deps with web3dart

Tags: dart, build, dependencies, angular-dart, web3dart

Trying to incorporate the [web3dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web3dart) package into my project. When I run **pub get** I receive the error:

> web3dart ^0.3.0 requires build_runner ^0.8.0.

When I change build_runner to ^0.8.0 my project will not build and I get the error:

> The `build_runner` version – 0.8.3 – is not within the allowed
>   constraint – >=0.8.10 <0.10.0.

Appears I'm in a bind, in need of advice on how to proceed.

pubspec.yaml for reference:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.67.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0-beta
  angular_components: ^0.9.0-beta
  angular_forms: ^2.0.0-beta
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+15
  firebase: ^5.0.0
  json_serializable: ^0.5.2
  web3dart: ^0.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0-beta
  build_runner: ^0.9.0
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ^0.4.0
  sass_builder: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: Try removing the version constraints for all of your dev dependencies and let pub version solver try

Comment: do you mean replace everything with "any"? Tried this but still got the same error: The build_runner version – 0.8.3 – is not within the allowed constraint – >=0.8.10 <0.10.0.

Comment: Try passing -v to get the full version solver logs